# Can we find the GCD of two polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ by representing the coefficients as vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, polynomials

> Can we find the GCD of two polynomials in $\mathbb Q[x]$ by representing the coefficients as vectors?

For example: $f=x^5+3x^4+x^3+4x^2+1$, and $g=x^5+3x^4+4x^3+3x+1$

Can we represent these polynomials as **f** $=(1,3,1,4,0,1)$ and **g** $=(1,3,4,0,3,1)$ and somehow perform matrix operations to find the GCD?

Comment: Excellent question. The  $GCD$ depends only on the coefficients, but as a function with multiple cases. In general, the $GCD$ will be the constant polynomial $1$, and this can be tested using the resultant being $\ne 0$. But if $R(f,g)=0$ then the $GCD$ is generically of degree $1$, unless other complicated algebraic conditions are satisfied, and so on, up to degree $n$ when it's simple again. Check for resultant http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resultant

Comment: Orangeskid's comment gives a very nice suggestion. If you want to mimic Euclid's algorithm instead (may be ok for, say, a computer implementation) you need to include the matrix operation corresponding to multiplying one of the rows by $x$. In other words, in addition to usual elementary row operations you need the operation of "adding a new row that is gotten from an existing one (that must begin with a zero) by shifting it one position to the left.

Comment: In Algebra the polynomial ring over a commutative ring $R$ is defined as the set of sequences in $R$, that eventually become constant equal to $0$. Therefore all algebraic operations must be expressible in terms of vectors, of varying length of course, as Jyrki already pointed out in the case of the Euclidean algorithm.